# jQuery Datepicker Can't be Reapplied after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

My HTML is setup similar to this this:

```
<div id='header'>
</div>
<div id='main'>
</div>
<div id='footer'?
</div>
```

Rather than change pages, when the user wants to navigate to a new area I simply load the HTML using $("#main").load("newFile.html"). On one file, I have a text input field that I apply a datepicker to. The datepicker field works fine initially, but if I try to reload the "main" no amount of calls to add a datepicker to that field will take. I am simply adding the datepicker via:

```
$("#myInput").datepicker();
```

If I only call the above once on initial load and don't try to reapply, it doesn't remember the original datepicker call, so it's not the repeat application of the above code. What can I do to make sure the datepicker always works?

Comment: And you put that code inside the **callback** for `load()`, so it executes when the content is actually loaded ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter when I load it. I can load the page without any datepicker, then add the datepicker in the console and it will work. Then when I reload the main div, the datepicker no longer works, and trying to add it again in the console fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with datepickers being dynamically loaded. There I had to resort to an ugly hack that relies on the inner workings of the datepicker plugin. As in

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").remove();
$(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```